# how to import psv data into Microsoft Access

Tags: csv, ms-access

I am using Access 2016, I have a psv (pipe delimetered csv) to be imported in a Access database, when I select import from text, the psv file doesn't show up in the File Browser:
[image]

Nor can I specify the psv directly:

[image]

How can I import psv into Access?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**

Per suggestion, after I changed the psv to txt and specify it to import, I stuck below:

It **DOESN't accept pipe** (or maybe any character) in the **Other** option. (wouldn't this look like a **BUG** if it doesn't accept any input here?)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I have Access 2016 as well, and when I go into the Import Text Wizard and get to the screen you posted, I can select any of the 5 delimiter options, and can type the pipe character in the Other box.  See my edit below to see the trouble I had when I tried again to get a screenshot for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. so the trick is to use a .txt in order to bypass the list restriction, and then use a back slash in the Others and then change it to pipe, after that it works as expected

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the lower right, and you'll see that you're limiting your view to only certain extensions.  The dropdown says `Text Files (*.txt;*.csv;*.tab;*.asc)`.  If you drop that box down, there should be an option for `All Files (*.*)` or something similar.

EDIT: [image]

It was very weird though.  At first it wouldn't take the pipe.  I clicked around and typed a `\` character in the Other box, and then was able to replace it with a pipe.

Comment: Thank you Matthew but there is no `All Files (*.*)` option or any similar.

Comment: Then maybe change the `.psv` file extension to match one of the ones on the list?  And the error message actually says that it has to have one of the extensions on that list.  Perhaps if you did what it suggested, you might see the file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work out, I've updated the OP with screenshot.