# SQL Import Wizard errors on importing a psv file

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am trying to import a psv (pipe delimited csv) into Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2 Express database table.

There are only two fields in the psv, each field has more than 1000 characters.

In the import wizard, I have the following settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Double checked in the mapping:

[image]

Note I set the option of Ignore on fail/truncate:
[image]

and **as usual**, I get an error:

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "Comm" returned status value 4 and status text
>   "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the
>   target code page.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

[image]

**UPDATE:**

So, following @Marc's suggestion, though very/extremely reluctant, I spent 3 hours or so to finally get SQL2014 installed on my computer and am hoping to import the psv. As expected, error shows up again:

[image]

I really cannot understand why company like Microsoft did not do thorough QAT on their products?!

Comment: Just as a side note: you *are aware* that SQL Server 2008 R2 is completely **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - it's high time to upgrade!

Comment: It's not for my work, it was on my home computer long time ago. but yes, let me see if I can find a free higher version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being tortured by Microsoft for the whole morning, I finally got this task done, for the future readers, you can follow the steps below to import a csv/psv data source into your sql:

1. Import the CSV/PSV to an Access Database. Note, must be saved to the mdb type (yes, the type from 20th century), you might want to read my story here: [how to import psv data into Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348617/how-to-import-psv-data-into-microsoft-access)
2. In your SQL (mine is 2014), start the Import Wizard and select the data source type (ACCESS) and the file. **Why you have to use mdb type of access database? Here you will see there is no option in SQL 2014 for accdb type of access database.**

[image]

3. DO NOT forget to select the right Destination (yes, even though you started the wizard by right click on the destination database and chose Import), you want to select the last option: SQL Native Client 11.0. That will show up the SQL2014 and the database.

[image]

Now that the import can be completed as expected.

Thanks to the great design logic in this SQL (2014? No, essentially no change compared to 2008), what a humble expectation and requirement!!! it costs me 4-5 hours to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use bulk insert to import any flat file.

```
if (object_id('dbo.usecase1') is not null)
    drop table dbo.usecase1
go

create table dbo.usecase1
(
    Descr nvarchar(2000) null,
    Comm nvarchar(2000) null
)
go

bulk insert dbo.usecase1
from 'C:\tmp\usecase0.psv'
with (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

go

[BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you, but, as suspected, it throws out some error: `Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)`, I believe the bulk insert needs to take care of encoding

Comment: You know what? As long as there is a working method, stick to it and don't do more research, otherwise, it will drive you crazy, for example, bulk insert won't work in my case, it doesn't work on UTF-8 encoding in SQL2014, unless you install SP2, to install SP2, you might be asked to install others,....endless. Really not worth.

Comment: You can use: codepage = '65001' for utf-8 data. You right, you must install sql server 2014 sp2 that match with the version and edition of installed sql server 2014 sp2 in your machine. By updating your sql server with service pack, of course your sql server could be more fix, more stable, more secure, and more add-ins features. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq